# Conditional Splitting in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix, text-processing

I have the following sentences:

```
my $sent = 'D. discoideum and D. purpureum developmental programs revealed';
```

Is there a way I can split the lines so that two consecutive words that have '.' (dot) in between will be treated as one word?

Hence we hope to get this after splitting:

```
$VAR = ['D. discoideum', 
         'and', 
         'D. purpureum',
         'developmental',
         'programs',  
         'revealed'];
```

The standard `s/\s+//g` will split everything based on space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try splitting on:

```
/(?<!\.)\s+/
```

This expression matches any space character that does not follow a period, without matching the period itself.

Comment: +1 - thanks, was just testing that when you commented. I thought I could do it without a lookahead/behind then realized that whole "Last letter isn't a period" part.

Answer (score 2):

Without a split using a regex:

```
my @words = $sent =~ /(\S+\.\s+\S+|\S+)/g;
```